# How to accummulate two datetime in two tables as VIEW in SQL Server 2014?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014

How to query to accumulate two datetime columns in two tables in SQL Server 2014? This is an example for your reference:

**Check-In** table

```
InID       UserID     CheckInTime
---------------------------------
IN-001     1          2018-11-10 08:00:00
IN-002     2          2018-11-15 07:00:00
```

**Check-Out** table

```
OutID      UserID     CheckOutTime
----------------------------------
OUT-001    1          2018-11-10 12:00:00
OUT-002    2          2018-11-15 14:00:00
```

Result set (expected)

```
ResultID     UserID    InID     OutID     WorkTimeinHour
--------------------------------------------------------
1            1         IN-001   OUT-001   4
2            2         IN-002   OUT-002   7
```

Comment: What should happen when there is another record for `OUT-001` in `Check-Out` table ?

Comment: that's my another issue, i will asked it after this one was solved

Comment: you have to add a `userid` for specified user's in and out data along with `date` column which will store date only. then we are able to join two table on basis of userid and date column

Comment: Change your table design. Avoid In and Out word in IntID and OutID columns. I think, It is related to employee details so employee table and it will not contain any prefix in the ID column in employee table. If you remove the In and Out word in IntID and OutID columns will help you to get the details straight forward and avoid manipulation in the SELECT statement. Create a foreign key with Employee table to bound the IDs.

Comment: @FannyKaunang - But answer to this question will be pretty useless. You need to fix your schema first. Store then `Id` & `In-Out` in separate column.

Comment: @Nayan i've edited my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Similar to @PSK, I used STUFF function to replace "IN-" and "OUT-" characters

But since these are in JOIN conditions, those operations will cause performance loss 
It is better to use a numeric column in both tables instead of useless "IN-" and "OUT-" containing string columns

```
select
    i.UserId, i.InID, CheckInTime, o.OutID, CheckOutTime,
    dbo.fn_CreateTimeFromSeconds(DATEDIFF(ss, CheckInTime, CheckOutTime)) as TotalTime
from CheckIn i
inner join CheckOut o
    on i.UserId = o.UserId and
       STUFF (i.InID,1,3,'') = STUFF (o.OutID,1,4,'')
```

Additionally, I used a custom user-defined fn_CreateTimeFromSeconds [function to format time](http://www.kodyaz.com/t-sql/calculate-time-operations-in-sql-server.aspx) for HH:MI:SS format

Hope it helps

Comment: thanks! i've edited my query by using a bit in your code

Answer (score 1):

For your current scenario, you can try like following.

Assuming that IN and OUT id after the "-" will be same as one entry.

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() 
         OVER( 
           ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS ResultIt, 
       T1.inid, 
       T2.outid, 
       DATEDIFF(hh, T2.checkouttime, T1.checkintime) 
FROM   checkin T1 
       INNER JOIN checkout T2 
               ON REPLACE(T1.inid, 'IN-', '') = REPLACE(T2.outid, 'OUT-', '')
```

This query will not perform good for huge data as REPLACE is being used in the JOIN. Ideally you should have a single identifier to identify the IN and OUT transaction.

Comment: according from your answer, i've modified my query and seems to works. thanks